# Docker Desktop Windows - How do you want to open this file?

Tags: windows, docker

I used to be able to run Docker on Windows and Linux no problem.
I installed this recently on my new PC and I keep getting "How do you want to open this file?" popup on every command that I run:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by installing Windows sub system - ubuntu in my case